# namespace in asp.net usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, user-controls

I make a asp.net usercontrol. its name is ucTreeview. in my page it named: uc1:ucTreeview
How can i rename uc1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you register the control you're declaring prefix using <%@ Register ...

http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/020319.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `assembly:TagPrefixAttribute` [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366537.aspx) on MSDN is a concise example of how to do that.