# How to specify a namespace for an ASP.net UserControl?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, namespaces

i have a `UserControl` in ASP.net:

**`GrobSelector.ascx.cs`**:

```
...
public partial class GrobSelector : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
   ...
```

i want to wrap this class in a namespace:

**`GrobSelector.ascx.cs`**:

```
...
namespace GrobSelectorNamespace
{
   public partial class GrobSelector : System.Web.UI.UserControl
   {
      ...
   ...       
}
```

Except now code fails to compile:

> ```
> public partial class GrobSelector : System.Web.UI.UserControl
> ```
>
> Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

What's the correct way to put an ASP.net `UserControl` in a namespace?

---

### Bonus Chatter

The *code in-front* file contains:

**`GrobSelector.ascx`**:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GrobSelector.ascx.cs" 
    Inherits="GrobSelector"  %>
```

### Bonus Reading

- [Putting a Web User Control (ascx) in a namespace?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1158378.aspx/1)
- [namespace in asp.net usercontrol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635418/namespace-in-asp-net-usercontrol)
- [Getting namespace name not found for ASP.net user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826129/getting-namespace-name-not-found-for-asp-net-user-control)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you received explains it correctly.

You should change your 'in-front' file such that the `Inherits` attribute takes into account the namespace in which the control class resides:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="VacationSelector.ascx.cs" 
    Inherits="VacationSelectorNamespace.VacationSelector"  %>
```

Comment: i assumed the `VacationSelector.ascx/VacationSelector.ascx.cs` took care of that!

Comment: It can be tricky.  But keep in mind that you don't necessarily have to have the same class name as the actual file.  This is to say that you can have a VacationSelector.ascx.cs whose class is actually 'foo' which makes it all the more necessary to include the fully qualified name of the class.