# Access constant from code behind in UserControl ASCX

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webusercontrol, vs-web-application-project

I have the following UserControl ASCX:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="TestUC.ascx.vb" Inherits="Common.DataQuery.TestUC" %>

<script>
    function fcTest() {
        alert('<%=lblTest.ClientID%>');
    }
</script>

<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTest" Text="test" />
Testing constant: <%=MAXT%>
End of test
```

And the ASCX.VB:

```
Namespace DataQuery

    Public Class TestUC
        Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

        Public Const MAXT = 10


        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            lblTest.Text = " dd"
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Currently getting error on the `<%=MAXT%>` statement, saying it's not defined.
Why?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue.. I literally added a new default ascx page, and added a public property IsTest as Bool, and I cannot see if from the ascx <% vb.code.goes.here %>. I don't get why

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the Namespace. Remove the begin namespace and end namespace and try. It would work. If you still need to give a namespace refer to this post how to specify one - 
[How to specify a namespace for an ASP.net UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789711/how-to-specify-a-namespace-for-an-asp-net-usercontrol)

Comment: I followed this post, it works but can't access the constant.

Comment: I believe that's because your .ascx says Inherits="Common.DataQuery.TestUC" and your code-behind says Namespace DataQuery. they both should be consistent. else, the code perhaps wouldn't even compile.

Comment: I created a new Web User Control (with default settings, no explicit namespace, etc.). Added the constant and tried to use it on the ASCX. No go.